# How to access static resource in JEST for lighting web component

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

We are importing JavaScript library in lwc using static resource, I want to test component using JEst. But static resource is not rendering while running the test class ? How can I render ?

Comment: Without showing us what your code is, it is not going to be easy answering it! I recommend you add what you tried and what error you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Since LWC Jest unit tests run locally and independent of the org, the static resource will not automatically load the same way it would in production if you use `lightning/platformResourceLoader` to load the resource.

To test how a component uses a Javascript library as a static resource, you can mock out `lightning/platformResourceLoader` and then `require` in the library from the local staticresources folder.

Here's the relevant sample code from a test in lwc-recipes that loads the `moment` library:

```
jest.mock(
    'lightning/platformResourceLoader',
    () => {
        return {
            loadScript() {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    // If the variable is false we're simulating an error when loading
                    // the script resource.
                    if (!mockScriptSuccess) {
                        reject('Could not load script');
                    } else {
                        global.moment = require('../../../staticresources/moment');
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            }
        };
    },
    { virtual: true }
);
```

Full test code [here](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/libsMomentjs/__tests__/libsMomentjs.test.js).

Comment: for those who also wonder where the test code went for moment.js https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/8ce0cac243faee23c42f56f6e22f34d62c4c1250/force-app/main/default/lwc/libsMomentjs/__tests__/libsMomentjs.test.js